# Git Bash for Windows 10 encounters path error when running "bq query" but not "bq mk" etc

Tags: bash, google-bigquery, gcloud, git-bash, bq

Everything that I describe below actually works on Windows Command Prompt, but I encounter some errors on my Git Bash. I'm using the latest version of git already `git version 2.25.0.windows.1`.

Basically when I try to execute `bq query ...`, my Bash runs into some PATH error that for some reason doesn't happen when I run other bq / gsutil / gcloud commands.

It seems that when I run `bq query...`, Bash stops scanning the PATH at the space in the words "Cloud SDK" (see the location under `where bq`).

```
MINGW64 /d/Code/gcp_apps/solutions-gcs-bq-streaming-functions-python (master)
$ where bq
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\bq.cmd

MINGW64 /d/Code/gcp_apps/solutions-gcs-bq-streaming-functions-python (master)
$ bq mk mydataset
BigQuery error in mk operation: Dataset 'inventory-265805:mydataset' already
exists.

MINGW64 /d/Code/gcp_apps/solutions-gcs-bq-streaming-functions-python (master)
$ bq query 'select first_name, last_name, dob from mydataset.mytable'
'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

There was an error when I executed `bq mk dataset`, but the point is that the command works.

So why is only `bq query ...` encountering the PATH error?

So far, my gcloud and gsutil all seem to be able to run normally.

Comment: what version of the Cloud SDK are you having this issue with?

Comment: ```Google Cloud SDK 279.0.0

bq 2.0.53

cloud-datastore-emulator 2.1.0

core 2020.01.31

gsutil 4.47```

Comment: I think you should open a ticket to the [PIT](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) for Cloud SDK since this seems like a bug to me. Nevertheless, try using a different version of the SDK before doing so in order to confirm that this happens because of the version